# Calculate the percentage of the current time and a moment with VueMoment/MomentJS

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I'm using [VueMoment](https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment) (VueJS filters for [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)) and I need to calculate the percentage of the current time and a moment.

```
Current time: 16:00 Uhr (24 hr format)  
Moment trigger time: 18:00 Uhr (24 hr format)
```

How to calculate the percentage with VueMoment?

Comment: Percentage of what? If you mean how close you are to the trigger time, a percentage would require a *start* time as well.

Comment: Show sample dates and what would the "percentage" be for them.